# How to enable echoing in telnet.exe client

Tags: windows, telnet

Can I somehow enable echoing in the standard telnet.exe client when connecting to the bat.org server? Is it possible at all?

> telnet bat.org

When I'm connecting to this server via putty, echoing works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098503/how-to-unsupress-local-echo

Comment: @barlop "set localecho" doesn't work

Comment: hmm, doesn't work for me either. I just tried `telnet webserver 80`  and yeah it doesn't type the letters you print, I can do GET<ENTER><ENTER> and it gives the output, but no echo.  Maybe part of it is that windows telnet is just rubbish. I hope this gets a good answer